# Giving a H1 element a random color

Tags: javascript, html, css

Can you explain me what is wrong with this code ?

```
var a = document.getElementById("id1").style.color;
```

`a = "blue"` is supposed to set the text color of the element with `id1` to blue

```
function randomColor() {
   var cArr = '1234567890ABCDEF'.split('');
   var c = "#";
   for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
       c += cArr[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)]
   }
   a = c;
   return c;
}
randomColor();
```

Looks pretty good to me but for sure it isn't because it isn't working.
Can you explain me what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: `document.getElementById("id1").style.color = randomColor();`

Comment: So `var a` is simply saving a reference to the color. When you need to change the color, you will need to use `document.getElementById("id1").style.color = c;`

Comment: Looks good to me: https://jsfiddle.net/rz2cwkdn/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> a = "blue" is supposed to set the text color of the element with id1 to blue

No that not true `a` contain the current color of the element `id1`.

To set the color you could store the element in variable then after that set the `blue` color to it like following :

```
var a = document.getElementById("id1");
a.style.color = "blue";
```

Hope this helps.

---

### Snippet

```js
function randomColor() {
  var cArr = '1234567890ABCDEF'.split('');
  var c = "#";
  
  for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    c += cArr[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)]
  }  

  return c;
}

var a = document.getElementById("id1");
a.style.color = randomColor();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 id="id1">H1 element</h1>
```

Comment: I though that I can somehow write less and do more. Thank you for such a fast answer

Answer (score 4):

You are setting `a` to a primitive value. Therfore you can not assign the color.

```js
function randomColor() {
   var c = "#";
   for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
       c += (Math.random() * 16 | 0).toString(16);
   } 
   return c;
}

var a = document.getElementById("id1").style;
a.color = randomColor();
```

```html
<h1 id="id1">stackoverflow</h1>
```

Answer (score 2):

To answer this question you need to understand how data is passed and stored in variables. You seem to know that objects are passed by reference, and if you store an object in several different variables you can modify one and it will be different in all of them.

However when you're storing an object's property in a variable, and that property has a plain data type such as number, string or boolean, that variable only stores the value not a reference. What you want to do is store the resulting element from your `document.getElementById` call in a `el` variable, then access its style.color within your function.

```
el.style.color = 'blue'
```